# Load fields based on selected option in add new product admin page

Tags: frontend, products-management, dropdown-attribute, admin-panel, custom-attributes

Hi Could someone help me with the following,

In Add new products page, I have an attribute 'code generate' with a dropdown list of values Yes, No. I need to show additional attribute fields such as 'name' and 'number of codes' if user selects Yes for the field 'code generate'.

All the additional attributes have already been created. I just want to know how to load other attributes based on Yes or No of the field 'code generate'

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This would need some javascripting as this is not possible with Magento's configuration alone.

They way I would do this is to make:

- one attribute with yes or no as an option.
- one attribute with a number of codes.

Display both normally but hide the second one in the template files using CSS (display:none;)

Then, add some javascript code to read the value of the first select attribute with a click event. If the read value is Yes, then display the second dropdown. If no then hide again.

I hope this helps a bit